# How to prevent a column break between a heading and the first row of a table?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create responsive columns that include several tables with headings. I want to prevent that a heading is at the bottom of the column. It sounds simple, but I can't get it to work.

I used the search extensively, read and tried the things that people suggested on Stackoverflow, but had no success. *(Plus: I'm using a javascript that creates the columns and it includes js classes that should be useful, but they don't work either. eMailed the dev, but he couldn't fix them.)*

I've also tried to use the break-before, break-after, break-inside CSS properties, but they don't seem to do anything in my case.

Would be extremely grateful if someone could point me to the right direction or tell me where the problem might be.

**In short:** 
Never break between the h2 Heading and the first table row:

```
<h2>Heading</h2>
<table class="table table-hover" >  
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
</table>
```

**Fiddle to try out:** 
http://jsfiddle.net/xjrt8qrm/

Comment: `td { white-space: nowrap; }`

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the reply. I don't think that comment answers my question.

Comment: We want to prevent that a heading is at the bottom of a column. Like this "Category Title" here: http://i.imgur.com/MT9XXkZ.png

Comment: put heading in table row...http://jsfiddle.net/xjrt8qrm/9/show/

Comment: Hey @Ankit - your solution doesn't work. In my browser (newest version of Chrome) it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/BQrfIEX.png (Old screenshot, same problem).

Thanks for your help. Is there anything else I should do to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

---

CSS:

```
.table
{
    position:relative;
    top:-20px;
}
```

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstood my question. I didn't mean that there should be no space between the heading and the text...

See: http://i.imgur.com/MT9XXkZ.png 

(the Category Title heading should be at the end of the column)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("h2").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this).next().find("tr").first().find("td");
    elem.css("border-top", "none");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjrt8qrm/2/

Fiddle ^

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But if it's already included in the fiddle it doesn't work. 

When I view the fiddle in full screen I still see a heading at the end of a column. If you have a different screen resolution you maybe don't. But check: http://jsfiddle.net/xjrt8qrm/2/show/

Answer (score 0):

```
.mytable table
 {
  -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
   -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
   column-break-inside:avoid;
 } 

.mytable h2
{
 -webkit-column-break-before:always;
 -moz-column-break-before:always;
  column-break-before:always;
 }
```

Comment: Please explain to the OP (and future visitors to SO) why you did what you did.

Comment: His solution doesn't work - so I explained it again visually. I don't understand why nobody here understands this question. Is it so badly explained, @JayBlanchard ?

Comment: An explanation added to an answer makes the answer a good answer, worthy of upvotes. Code only answers, while they may be correct, are not considered good answers @Faiz

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is, you want the h2 and the table to not split when it gets columnized. I'll assume you're using the Wulf columnizer as it is what you were using in fiddle. If that's the case, then you should wrap the h2 and the table into a container and add the class "dontsplit" to prevent chopping on that section.

Example using your code:

```
<div class="dontsplit">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

To prevent the h2 to be placed at the end of the column, use "dontend" class.

```
<h2 class="dontend">Heading</h2>
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Almost. I want it to split, but just not directly after the heading. (I explained it visually here: http://i.imgur.com/kmd620p.png)

This would be the code: 

`<div class="dontsplit">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<table class="table table-hover">
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
</div>
<tr><td>Title Here</td><td class="vert-align">Description</td></tr>
</table>`

But, the Columnizer plugin doesn't work correctly. The dontsplit or dontend don't seem to do anything. That's why I'm looking for a different way here using html/css.

Comment: Guess I can't end the </div> inside the <table>, BUT there's also the dontend class that could be used on the heading. Sadly it doesn't seem to work. No clue why. Messing with that might take too long, - looking for a simple CSS/html solution if possible.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean. Use the "dontend" class to the h2 tag. Thus, <h2 class="dontend">Heading</h2>

Comment: I said in the OP that these classes don't work. And in the last comment I also said that the dontend doesn't work. =/ Guess you missed that. Quickly try it in the JS fiddle next time. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Place every table and related heading in a div. [Here](http://tinyurl.com/nnqmgua) is an example.